# Credentials error when publishing in Nexus with Ivy

Tags: ant, nexus, ivy

I tried to found a solution to my problem in the publishing post but I couldn't find anything (neither in stackoverflow nor in google)

I'm trying to publishing some artifacts to Nexus using IVY but I'm obtaining credentials error.

In my ivysettings.xml I defined the credentials tag, but it's not working fine (I tried to put the concrete user and pass and doesn't work). If I put the /nexus in the host value as follows:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="nexus"/>
    <credentials host="${host}/nexus" realm="Nexus Repository Manager"
                        username="${user}" passwd="${pass}"/>

    <property name="nexus-public" value="${nexus.url}/content/groups/public"/>
    <property name="nexus-releases" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases"/>
    <property name="nexus-snapshots" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/ricrepo/"/>
    <property name="nexus-other" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases/"/>


    <resolvers>
            <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false" root="${nexus-public}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-releases" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-releases}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-other" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-other}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-snapshots" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-snapshots}" checkmodified="true" 
            changingPattern="*-SNAPSHOT"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

${host} it's just ${nexus.url} without https:// prefix and without /nexus at the end

And the error is:

```
[ivy:publish] INFO: Authentication requested but doAuthentication is disabled
Access to URL MYURL was refused by the server
```

Where MYURL is my complete URL with the repository (so it is resolving well the name...I think)

If I delete de /nexus from the host value (ivysettings would be as follows)

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="nexus"/>
    <credentials host="${host}" realm="Nexus Repository Manager"
                        username="${user}" passwd="${pass}"/>

    <property name="nexus-public" value="${nexus.url}/content/groups/public"/>
    <property name="nexus-releases" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases"/>
    <property name="nexus-snapshots" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/ricrepo/"/>
    <property name="nexus-other" value="${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases/"/>


    <resolvers>
            <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false" root="${nexus-public}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-releases" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-releases}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-other" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-other}"/>
            <ibiblio name="nexus-snapshots" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-snapshots}" checkmodified="true" 
            changingPattern="*-SNAPSHOT"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The error is:

```
[ivy:publish] INFO: No credentials available for BASIC 'Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager'
Access to URL MYURL was refused by the server
```

Please, anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the realm to "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager":

```
<credentials host="${host}" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="${user}" passwd="${pass}"/>
```